# What is wrong with my Stack Overflow account?

Tags: support, accounts, deleted-users

This morning I tried to connect to Stack Overflow and it suggested that I create a new account...

I created it, and I saw this:
([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgTeR.png)).

You can see that on the menu I have a history, with questions and answers and on my home I am at zero. In addition, the posts that have survived (some are marked deleted) are noted as written by userxxxxxx and not by me!

Also I didn't receive any emails notifying my of any deletion. Any ideas?

Comment: The "userxxxxxx" is likely you, just with a more anonymized name. You didn't try to close your account before?

Comment: Nop, my account just look like it has been removed... And I have a post with a lot of work that also seems to be deleted. All this without any warning, it's rather annoying.

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5338600/florian-z) your account, by any chance? It's possible that you failed to log in to it. Seems like there is [another](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8815766/florian-z) account with the same name that was deleted.

Comment: Hmm, looking into it further - yes, the deleted user *was* you. Not sure what's happening - you have the notifications from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60115671/) which is from February in the screenshot and yet you also have a new user apparently registered 4 days ago. The last snapshot of your old user in the Wayback machine is [from 19th of Match](https://web.archive.org/web/20200319091231/https://stackoverflow.com/users/8815766/florian-z). Not sure what means anything other than the old registration was still alive at that point.

Comment: You should really contact support by using the "contact us" Link in the footer.

Comment: Thank all, my account has been delete because I gave too many points to members of my team, it was perceived as fraud.